# kubectl command to GKE-Autopilot sometimes return forbidden error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

### env

- GKE Autopilot v1.22.12-gke.2300
- use kubectl command from ubuntu2004 VM
- use [gke-gcloud-auth-plugin](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/auth-plugin?hl=en)

### what happens

kubectl command sometimes return (Forbidden) error. e.g.)

```
kubectl get pod
```

> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "my-mail@domain.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default": GKEAutopilot authz: the request was sent before policy enforcement is enabled

It happens **not always**, so it must not be IAM problem. (it happens about 40%).
Before, I thinks it was GKE Autopilot v1.21.xxxx, this error didn't happen; at least not such frequently.

I couldn't find any helpful info even if I searched "GKEAutopilot authz", or "the request was sent before policy enforcement is enabled"

I wish if someone who faced to same issue has any idea.

Thank you in advance

Comment: We'll look into this.  Have you filed a bug with support as well?

Comment: Thank you. I asked google support and it solved

Answer (score 1):

I asked google cloud support.
They said it's bug on GKE master, and was fixed by them.

This problem doesn't happen anymore